# Parsing xml with more than one xmlns in it in T-SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql

I've got a problem with parsing XML file having two nested xmlns namespaces (both are the same) with OPENXML.

I already read a lot of stuff including [this topic on stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121852/parsing-typed-xml-with-a-default-namespace-and-inconsistent-root-node/121912#121912) but it doesn't help in my situation. Below I've paste some of XML code (sorry that all fields are in polish cause it's a response from bank webservice). If I select for DaneZapytaniaFin object

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://bik.pl/cc/big')
SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/BIGIMResponse/DaneZapytaniaFin')
```

I get all values that are in it.

But when I'm trying to get eg. a name field

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://bik.pl/cc/big')
SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/BIGIMResponse/DaneZapytaniaFin/dane-id-kons/imie')
```

only I'm getting is null value.

The same is when I'm trying to get it's parent node, dane-id-kons

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://bik.pl/cc/big')
SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/BIGIMResponse/DaneZapytaniaFin/dane-id-kons')
```

it's null.

Could somebody give me some advice how to get these values? Thanks in advance!

My XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BIGIMResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <DaneZapytaniaFin>
        <forma-pr-podm forma-pr-podm="01" xmlns="http://bik.pl/cc/big" />
        <dane-id-kons form-przek-nazw-i-im="01" imie="NAME" nazw="SURNAME" pesel="1234567890" rodz-dok-tozs="ID" seria-nr-dok-tozs="ABC123456" obywatelstwo="PL" xmlns="http://bik.pl/cc/big" />
        <daty-upow data-up-15-1="2019-11-22T00:00:00" data-up-24-1="2019-11-22T00:00:00" data-up-bik="2019-11-22T00:00:00" data-up-zbp="2019-11-22T00:00:00" xmlns="http://bik.pl/cc/big" />
    </DaneZapytaniaFin>
</BIGIMResponse>
```

and I'm reading it directly from filepath like:

```
create table #p_TempDM (dane xml)
declare @idoc INT
declare @sql varchar(max) 
    set @sql = '
        insert into #p_TempDM select CONVERT(xml, bulkcolumn, 2) imp from
        openrowset (bulk '''+@filePath+''', single_blob) as dane
        '
        exec (@sql)

declare @x xml

select @x =      dane from  #p_TempDM   
                 EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument
                 @idoc OUTPUT,
                 @x;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please keep in mind, that `FROM OPENXML` is outdated and should not be used any more. There are the much mightier [native XML-methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods?view=sql-server-2017).

Try this

Your XML

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BIGIMResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <DaneZapytaniaFin>
        <forma-pr-podm forma-pr-podm="01" xmlns="http://bik.pl/cc/big" />
        <dane-id-kons form-przek-nazw-i-im="01" imie="NAME" nazw="SURNAME" pesel="1234567890" rodz-dok-tozs="ID" seria-nr-dok-tozs="ABC123456" obywatelstwo="PL" xmlns="http://bik.pl/cc/big" />
        <daty-upow data-up-15-1="2019-11-22T00:00:00" data-up-24-1="2019-11-22T00:00:00" data-up-bik="2019-11-22T00:00:00" data-up-zbp="2019-11-22T00:00:00" xmlns="http://bik.pl/cc/big" />
    </DaneZapytaniaFin>
</BIGIMResponse>';
```

--In this case I declare the default namespace, but - important to see! - the first two levels are NOT living within this default namespace (it is declared on a deeper level). To solve this I use the *namespace wildcard* (like here `/*:BIGIMResponse`). In general, this is not recommended, but here it seems acceptable. You can use this approach to address each value separately and typed:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://bik.pl/cc/big')
SELECT @xml.value('(/*:BIGIMResponse/*:DaneZapytaniaFin/forma-pr-podm/@forma-pr-podm)[1]','int')
      ,@xml.value('(/*:BIGIMResponse/*:DaneZapytaniaFin/dane-id-kons/@form-przek-nazw-i-im)[1]','int') 
      ,@xml.value('(/*:BIGIMResponse/*:DaneZapytaniaFin/dane-id-kons/@imie)[1]','nvarchar(max)') 
      --and so on
```

--Another approach is a more generic *reading to an EAV*:

```
SELECT A.nds.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS ElementName
      ,B.attrs.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS AttributeName
      ,B.attrs.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS AttributeValue
FROM @xml.nodes('//BIGIMResponse/DaneZapytaniaFin/*') A(nds)
CROSS APPLY A.nds.nodes('@*') B(attrs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your example XML, if you're trying to select the name field your XPath is wrong:

`/BIGIMResponse/DaneZapytaniaFin/dane-id-kons/imie`

That selects an *element* but you're trying to select an *attribute*.

Try this for selecting that attribute:

`/BIGIMResponse/DaneZapytaniaFin/dane-id-kons/@imie`

Note the `@` that specifies you are trying to select an attribute. However, if you're having issues with the default namespace with that XPath you could try the following (it works for me in an XPath evaluator):

`/BIGIMResponse/DaneZapytaniaFin/*[name()='dane-id-kons']/@imie`

For where you are trying to select the `dane-id-kons` element you could alter your XPath to look using the `local-name` or`name`:

`/BIGIMResponse/DaneZapytaniaFin/*[local-name()="dane-id-kons"]`

`/BIGIMResponse/DaneZapytaniaFin/*[name()="dane-id-kons"]`

I hope this helps.